# how to run jupyter with virtualenv in mac

Tags: macos, keras, virtualenv

I have done the following steps in mac, to run a python program in terminal and jupyter:

```
0. install python3 and virtualenv:
    install python3.6.8 binary from python.org
    sudo pip3 install virtualenv
    which python3 # this is /usr/local/bin/python3
    which pip3 # this is /usr/local/bin/pip3
    which virtualenv # this is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv   
1. create a virtualenv, with python3:
    virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.6 keras
2. activate the virtualenv:
    source keras/bin/activate
3. install keras and jupyter in the env:
    (keras) pip3 install tensorflow keras jupyter
    (keras) which python   # this prints /Users/xxx/envs/keras/bin/python
    (keras) which python3  # this prints /Users/xxx/envs/keras/bin/python3
    (keras) which jupyter  # this prints /Users/xxx/envs/keras/bin/jupyter
4. run from terminal:
    (keras) python
    >>> import sys
    >>> print(sys.version)  # this prints 3.6.8
    >>> import keras
    >>> print(keras.__version__)  # this prints 2.2.4
    >>> exit()
5. run from jupyter (in the same virtualenv, with safari browser):
    (keras) jupyter notebook
        import sys
        print(sys.version)  # prints 3.6.8
        import keras  # gives error, no module named 'keras'
```

But the same code used to work in ubuntu-18.04, with chrome browser. So how do I run jupyter with virtualenv in mac, so that I can access the imported modules? Is there any step that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this problem for about an hour, it suddenly started working on its own. It is possible that macos was internally trying to locate and link its libraries, and that took some time.

Now when I do "help('modules')", it includes keras in the list.